# Mismatched types. Expected i32, found ()

Tags: types, rust

This code:

```
fn ackermann(m: i32, n: i32) -> i32 {
    if m == 0 {
        return n + 1;
    } else if m > 0 && n == 0 {
        return ackermann(m - 1, 1);
    } else if m > 0 && n > 0 {
        return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1));
    }
}
```

Has an error during compilation:

```
error: mismatched types [--explain E0308]
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |>
3 |>     if m == 0 {
  |>     ^ expected i32, found ()
note: expected type `i32`
note:    found type `()`
```

Comment: You could use `u32` and just `else` for the last branch. (And probably `u8` for `m` and `u64` for the rest would be more appropriate.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not all of your code paths return a value. You can fix this a few ways.. but since this appears to be a recursive function.. you probably want a way to break the recursion:

```
fn ackermann(m: i32, n: i32) -> i32 {
    if m == 0 {
        return n + 1;
    } else if m > 0 && n == 0 {
        return ackermann(m - 1, 1);
    } else if m > 0 && n > 0 {
        return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1));
    }

    return 0; // This breaks your recursion
}
```

Or, perhaps an explicit `else`:

```
if m == 0 {
    return n + 1;
} else if m > 0 && n == 0 {
    return ackermann(m - 1, 1);
} else if m > 0 && n > 0 {
    return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1));
} else { // An explicit else also works
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't put much thought into what this algorithm is/does.. but the error is pretty clear. How you break your recursion and have the function return an actual value is up to you.

*EDIT*: Benjamin has pointed out in the comments that this specific function should not actually reach outside of the conditionals you've provided. As such, some other options include panic'ing if the code does get out or perhaps returning `Result<i32>` instead.

The TLDR is: if none of your conditionals are met.. then the function won't return anything when its expected to return a number.

Comment: Or perhaps the function should panic, since the ackermann function is not defined for argument combinations other than these three. Either that or it should return a `Result` instead.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I didn't review the specifics. I'll add a few other options as per your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, don't think too hard about the function, it's supposed to be difficult to compute. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Comment: I think with the else you can actually drop the returns and semi-colons