# Expected () but found a struct

Tags: rust

I have a world object:

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

use super::world::World;

pub struct Worlds {
    worlds: Vec<World>
}

impl Worlds {
    pub fn new(world: Vec<World>) -> Worlds {
        Worlds { worlds: world }
    }

    pub fn get_random_world(&self) -> World {
        let mut rng = thread_rng();

        if self.worlds.len() > 0 {
            let world_index: usize = rng.gen_range(0, self.worlds.len());

            self.worlds[world_index]
        }

        self.worlds[0]
    }
}
```

The structure `Worlds` takes a vector of structures called `World` (I can post that code if you need it).

`get_random_world` is supposed to return a `World` structure, and does with `self.worlds[world_index]`, but apparently it expects a `()`.

I'm lost; I told it what to return, it returns that but it expects something different?

```
   |
20 |             self.worlds[world_index]
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found struct `game::world::world::World`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
   = note:    found type `game::world::world::World`
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/24579756/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/37554325/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/24502282/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/39522242/155423 and probably others.

Comment: If `self.worlds.len() > 0` is *not* true, the length is 0 and indexing at 0 will panic. You might want to return an `Option<World>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` block doesn't return anything.. flow will fall through here:

```
if self.worlds.len() > 0 {
    let world_index: usize = rng.gen_range(0, self.worlds.len());

    self.worlds[world_index]
} // <--- ... this drops down

self.worlds[0]
```

Here is a simple reproduction of your issue: [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=43ddb2d89bf51f277a4e476e942f8e1c&version=stable&backtrace=0)

There are two ways you can fix this. First, you can explicitly return in the conditional ([View it on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0f7fb465e664d21eafc9ab02f1ec752c&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
if self.worlds.len() > 0 {
    let world_index: usize = rng.gen_range(0, self.worlds.len());

    return self.worlds[world_index]; // Explicitly return out of here
} 

self.worlds[0]
```

The more "idiomatic" approach I guess would be to add an `else` block, so that the value the conditional evaluates to is actually what the function returns ([View it on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f71b7d86c8e4bf63943f62c0b5b32ecf&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
if self.worlds.len() > 0 {
    let world_index: usize = rng.gen_range(0, self.worlds.len());

    self.worlds[world_index]
} else {
    self.worlds[0]
}
```

Now, no matter what logical branch the code takes, the expression that results will be returned from the function.

Comment: Ahh this makes sense. I thought with out the `return` keyword, rust would know "ok he doesn't use a `;` so he must want to return" Thanks :)

Comment: You're correct... except it doesn't assume "so he must want to return _from the function_". Everything is an expression in Rust - everything returns a value. Your `if` conditional here is what Rust is assuming "wants to return" a value from. Its not assigned to anything and so Rust expects it'll return unit (which is `()`.. nothing). Instead, your conditional evaluates to a `World` instance: hence the error.