# Executing actions on a HashMap depending on whether a key exists or not

Tags: hashmap, rust, option-type

I wrote a struct `Edge` which represents a tuple of points, given by IDs as `u16` types.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Edge {
    left: u16,
    right: u16,
}
```

In my main function, I have a `Vector` of edges and a `HashMap` which maps every point ID to a `Vector` of all edges of which it is the `left` object.

To fill the `HashMap`, I iterate over the `Vector` of edges, check if the `left` value of the edge is already a key in the `HashMap`, and if so, I simply add the edge to the `Vector` of edges, and if not, I insert the new key and value.

```
let mut map = HashMap::<u16, Vec<Edge>>::new();
let edge_list: Vec<Edge> = vec![];  // emptiness of this vector should not affect the code

for edge in edge_list.iter() {
    match map.get(&edge.left) {
        Some(x) => x.push(*edge),
        None => map.insert(edge.left, vec![*edge]),
    }       
}
```

However, the compiler does not like my code:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |         match map.get(&edge.left) {
   |         ^ expected (), found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
   = note:    found type `std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<Edge>>`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
  --> src/main.rs:16:21
   |
16 |             None => map.insert(edge.left, vec![*edge]),
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't know what it is expecting. `map.get(...)` should return an `Option`, i.e. it is either `Some(x)` or `None`, and I am evaluating both cases. I have seen a bunch of cases where `match` was used to deconstruct an `Option`. Why would `match` expect `()`? What could be wrong?

Comment: @Shepmaster this code has a different problem than the code in your duplicate.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt it's true, but I'm answering (duplicating) based on the question asked in the title. Trying to solving the OPs problem, as I don't suppose they want to hear the direct answer: "All blocks in an `if` statement must return the same type, and `Vec::push` and `HashMap::insert` don't have the same type".

Comment: If that's what OP is interested in, this can be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/24579756/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/37554325/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/24502282/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/39522242/155423; or potentially others.

Comment: @GeckStar: does this help? I really want to know if all of this is actually helpful to you or not. And if not, how you would expect/hope this question is handled?

Comment: I'm currently checking out the duplicate, which means that I'm looking into how to use `Entry`. The code snippets from the other duplicates in Shepmaster's second comment gave me more ideas on what to use if I fail to get it right with `Entry`, e.g. using `if`clauses with `map.contains_key(key)`. The best answer would have been to suggest an alternative to the match construct in my answer imo, since I'm understand from Shepmaster's first comment that I'm trying something here that is inherently flawed, that is using statements returning different types within a `match` block.

Comment: I hope you don't read too much negativity into my duplicate closing. Like @LukasKalbertodt says, we *do* want to answer questions, but I don't want to rewrite the same answers for every specific permutation of submitted code.

Comment: FWIW, you **cannot** use the `match` or `if` form combined with `get` because of borrowing issues. That's the *reason* that the `Entry` API was created, so that entire direction would be a dead end. There's also issues with immutable vs mutable borrowing, moving out out borrowed content, etc.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't read any negativity into your duplicate closing, if anything that just showed me that I didn't search thoroughly enough for the problem. I have only started learning Rust this week though, so I'm currently lacking the skill to put the problems I'm facing into words, which makes it hard to search for this stuff.